# NodeJS+Express: serving static files for diffrerent URLs

Tags: node.js, static, routes, express

I'm using node.js+express for serving static files (CSS+JS). At this time static dir is configured as

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

In main templeate layout.jade I load static files as

```
link(href='css/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

Everything works fine with pages like /hello, /write, /:user. But when I get pages like /bob/505b6833d3835d3705000001/edit, static files cannot be found. Firebug shows Node generates  the same path for static, but styles are not applied for the page. Why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should that link just be /css/bootstrap.css? (notice pre slash)

Comment: it worked, thanks. Please, reply as s full answer - I'll mark your reply as best, and you'll be able to get some reputaion points ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using link with pre-slash.

```
link(href='/css/bootstrap.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

This should take care of it.

Comment: However, I've found my problem is not solved. I've noticed that this line: app.get('/:user/:postid', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {...} conflicts with static files paths. I have to try to separate it from main code...

Comment: Do you want the routes to run first?

Comment: Well, what do you mean 'first'? I thought routes start when request is got, and rendering page with static css is the last that node does

Comment: Well the middleware and the routes will run in the order they are added to the express app. So if the first thing you do is add the static middleware then it will run before running any route.

Comment: I've tried to move app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static/media/content')); to every place in my app.js file - still can't get css working(( The problem occurs only if I add app.get('/:user/:postid', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {...} function to my code

Comment: You might need to do something like redirect:false in the static middleware. Covered at the very bottom of this post http://blog.modulus.io/route-stats-to-the-rescue

Comment: added { maxAge: 86400000 /* one day */ , redirect: false })); - didn't work for me((

Comment: I have no ideas about this problem. Just turned app.get('/:user/:postid', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {...}  to app.get('/:user/:postid/comment', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {...} and it works now. However, I understand it's a so-so solution...

Comment: You need to put `app.use(app.router)` ahead of `app.use(express.static...)` so that all routes will be tried before the static server.