# Express serving static files for multiple paths using regex

Tags: node.js, express

I've different paths in my app like:

- `/a`
- `/a/:b`
- `/a/:/b/:c/:d`

For paths like `/a`, I use:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

For paths like `/a/:b`, I add another like this:

```
app.use('/a', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Instead of adding `express.static` for every path, is there any way to achieve this using a single line of code possibly by using regex.
Something like:

```
app.use(/\/[a-z]*/, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// BTW, this doesn't work
```

What would be a good practice to serve static files for multiple paths? Thank you.

Comment: why don't you just store your static files in one folder with subfolder a / b / c / whatever?

Comment: If  your file storage disk hierarchy matches the URL path hierarchy, then you can put all the files in one disk hierarchy and use just one `express.static()` call for everything by just specifying the top level.  `express.static()` will do multiple levels for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, it is solved by adding a pre-slash on static links.

Comment: @dragfire - which is not something you showed us in your question at all so we could have no idea that's what you were doing in your source files.  Anyway, glad you figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to add trailing slash:

```
app.all(/\/[a-z]*/, function(req, res) { 
    res.redirect('/static/'); 
});
app.use('/static/', express.static( __dirname + '/public' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by adding all static links a pre-slash.
For example:

```
<link href='/lib/csss/bstrap.min.js' />
```

instead of

```
<link href='lib/csss/bstrap.min.js' />
```

[NodeJS+Express: serving static files for diffrerent URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519285/nodejsexpress-serving-static-files-for-diffrerent-urls)